# How to fill multiple models with mongodb using "population"

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am trying to display all the data with the "populate" statement. But I only get one "populate" but when I put many it doesn't work.
what I want to do is to bring me the data from the "User", "Customer" model as well.

This is my code

My Model:

```js
import { model, Schema } from 'mongoose';

const RoomSchema = new Schema({
  Users: [
    {
      agentId: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "User",
        required: false,
      },
      customerId: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "Customer",
        required: false,
      },
      typeId: Number, // 1 - agent, 2 - client
    },
  ],
  Messages: [
    {
      agentId: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "User",
        required: false,
      },
      customerId: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "Customer",
        required: false,
      },
      message: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
      },
      date: Date,
      sender: Number,
    },
  ],
  FinishAt: Date,
  FinishBy: String,
  typeFinishBy: Number, // 1 - agent, 2 - client
}, {
    timestamps: true,
    versionKey: false
});

export default model('Room', RoomSchema);
```

this is the sentence I am using

```
import Room from "../models/Room.js";

async function getOnlyRoom(id) {

 const foundRoom = await Room.findById(id)
 .populate('Users.agentId')
 .populate('Users.customerId')
 .populate('Messages.agentId')
 .populate('Messages.customerId')
 .execPopulate();

  return foundRoom
}
```

[Image of Json Postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fMMRl.png)

only works with one

```
foundRoom.populate('Users.customerId')
```

[Works with only populate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LkuLc.png)

this is the error
[image of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NvRrU.png)

Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution to my problem
I was researching the solution on the mongoose website and did it with a single populate.

```
 const populateRoom = await foundRoom
.populate([
  { path: 'Users.agentId', select: 'name' },
  { path: 'Users.customerId', select: 'name' },
  { path: 'Messages.agentId', select: 'name' },
  { path: 'Messages.customerId', select: 'name' }
])

return populateRoom;
```

Comment: you can use aggregate with lookup too